# Is it possible to have left-aligned text in a combobox whose 'RightToLeft' property is set to 'Yes'?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, text, combobox

I have a combobox on a form whose 'RightToLeft' property is set to 'Yes' - this places the drop-down arrow on the lefthand side of the control and the text is on the right as shown below.

[X_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_My Text]

But what I would like to have is this if it's possible? And if so how do I achieve it?

[XMy Text_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**]

Thanks for your feedback on this.

Comment: Don't use RightToLeft, it is only appropriate for RTL languages like Arabic and Hebrew.  It causes rendering problems for English text, you haven't seen any only by accident.  Try "[My Text]" for example. Every non middle-eastern user expects the arrow on the right.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. SO is asking me if I've considered selecting an answer for this. If you repost your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant says:

> Don't use RightToLeft, it is only appropriate for RTL languages like
>   Arabic and Hebrew. It causes rendering problems for English text, you
>   haven't seen any only by accident. Try "[My Text]" for example. Every
>   non middle-eastern user expects the arrow on the right.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control and use [`ComboBoxRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer.aspx) to draw the arrow where you want.